# CSS not displaying properly after transferred to IIS 7 in IE 9

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer

When running on dev server through VS 2010 all CSS displays properly.  I publish to win server 2008 r2 with IIS 7, and when I open in IE 9 the inline-block doesnt work, the gradients dont work, and the box-shadow doesnt work.  It strips out most of the CSS formatting, I load the same page in firefox and it looks the same as it does in IE 9 under the dev server.  Code below:
CSS file:

```
body {
}
#opsChartContainer
{
    background: #FFFFFF;
margin: auto;
width: 600px;
padding-top: 15px;
font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
display: inline-table;
}
#oldestActiveCon
{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    display: inline-table;
}
#incVolumeCon
{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: auto;
    width: 700px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    display: inline-table;
}
#reqSLACon
{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: auto;
    width: 400px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    display: inline-table;
}

h1
{
    background: #e3e3e3;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfdfe, #8bb7e3);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fcfdfe), to(#8bb7e3));
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #292929;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #292929;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #292929;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#fcfdfe,     endColorstr=#8bb7e3)";
    color: #454545;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h2
{
    background: #dde3d5;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #292929;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #292929;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #b5baae;
    color: #454545;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
    font-size: small;
    font-style: normal;
}
.mGrid { 
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 5px 0 10px 0; 
    border: solid 1px #525252; 
    border-collapse:collapse; 
}
.mGrid td { 
    padding: 2px; 


}
.header
{
    padding: 4px 2px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #4289c6 url('../grd_head.png') repeat-x top;
}
.alt
{
    background: #FFFFFF url('../grd_alt.png') repeat-x top;
    font-size: smaller;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style: normal;
}
.rst
{
    background: #FFFFFF url('../grd_firstt.png') repeat-x top;
    font-size: smaller;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style: normal;
}

ul#testy li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

ASPX front end:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"     CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test.test" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">




</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div id="opsChartContainer"><h1>TEXT</h1><h2>FLASHFILE</h2></div>
<div id="oldestActiveCon"><h1>TEXT</h1>
<h2>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
        ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="200px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
                SortExpression="Status" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Team" HeaderText="Team" SortExpression="Team" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="Time" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Request ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Target="_blank"     NavigateUrl='<%    # "link"+ Eval("Request") + "&"%>'><%#Eval("Request")%></asp:HyperLink>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

        <HeaderStyle CssClass="header" />

<RowStyle CssClass="rst"></RowStyle>

    </asp:GridView>
</h2>
</div>


<div id="incVolumeCon">
    <h1>text</h1>
    <h2>
        flashfile
    </h2>
</div>
<div id="reqSLACon">
    <h1> text</h1>  
        <h2>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="blahblah" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" CssClass="mGrid" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" RowStyle-CssClass="rst" Width = "400">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="text" HeaderText="text" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="text" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Dueby Time" HeaderText="text" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="text" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="text" HeaderText="text" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="text" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="text" HeaderText="text" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="text" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr1" HeaderText="text" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="Expr1" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Request ID" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# "link"+ Eval("Request ID") + "&"%>'><%#Eval("Request ID")%></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>

test
    </h2>
</div>
```

ANY ideas?  What is causing the disparity between when I view it in IE 9 through dev server from vs 2010 and when I view it in IE 9 on production server?

Comment: Does *any* CSS rule from your stylesheet apply? Please run `javascript:alert(document.compatMode + '\n' + document.documentMode)` from the address bar and tell us what's the result.

Comment: is your IE 9 running in compatability mode?  (when your looking at the production server)

Comment: No its not, and i also tested in ie 8 and 7 with the same results.  some of the CSS applies but not all.

Comment: how do I run javascript:alert(document.compatMode + '\n' + document.documentMode) in the address bar?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your page is running with a Document Mode other than "IE 9 Standards".

Hit F12 to bring up the Developer Tools to see which it actually is.

See here for instructions to work out *why* this is happening: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#ie8modes

Otherwise, you can fix it by adding this to the top of your `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

This will force IE to use its most up-to-date rendering engine.

**This can be done in IIS server also by settings in HTTP Response Header.**
IN the Name field put "X-UA-Compatible" and in the Value field put "IE=Edge" 
in EDIT Custom HTTP Response Header as below image.

[image]

Comment: THANK you!! it was the document mode

Comment: No problem. Note that you can't just change the Document Mode - that will only work for you. You need to add that `meta` tag. That will set the right Document Mode for everybody else. Also, please [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it worked for you.

Comment: +1 for the best practice way to use the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag, in contrast to the other answer which recommended setting it to IE8.

Comment: How do you check in F12 whether the page is running with a document mode other than "IE 9 standards"?  Where can I find that information?

Comment: Found the current document mode under "Emulation" tab.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem on a couple of websites. It rendered correctly in all browsers (That I tested) except IE9. I solved it by inserting `<meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />` in the HEADER.

**But with me situation it did not work anywhere locally or remotely, so if your rendering locally it could be something else but it's worth a try.**

Hope that helps....

Comment: Absolutely not -- this forces IE9 into IE8 compatibility mode, which basically means throwing away all the new features. You should make sure you know what mode it is running in, and make sure it's running in the best mode available (that is, IE9 standard mode), but any time you consider setting a site to default into backward compatibility mode, you'd be better off fixing the problems in your code that make you want to do that, because they'll probably mean you're breaking in other browsers too.

Comment: @Spudley - It was a bug in http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/ that broke in IE9, this was just a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Did you manually go to the URL of the CSS file on the server and see what it displays? I expect it will be a 500 Internal Server Error or similar response instead of actual CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

We had issue on alignment and border, it were getting changed after deployement,

After putting this tag in master page just after the DOCTYPE, all things are looking same as they look on local.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```